# z-index seems to not be working properly

Tags: html, css, z-index

I am trying to create a div that shows more text on hover, and have the text that shows up be centered.  I have those 2 parts working but for some reason the z-index isn't working.

```css
.popup-title-side {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Gamecube;
    font-size: 6px;
    color: #f00;
    line-height: 13px;
    cursor: default;
    z-index: 1001;
    background-color: #888;
}

.popup-body-side {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Gamecube;
    font-size: 6px;
    line-height: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1000;
    /*min-height: 200px;*/
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
       -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
           transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

That is the code I am using but for some reason the `.popup-body-side` is showing on top of the `.popup-title-side`

[View the issue here](http://test.jaketr00.tk/div_hover_test/friends)

**EDIT** I did not understand the other answer that caused this question to be marked duplicate, I did not realize that it meant that you *MUST* have a position tag.  I am sorry.

Comment: And the relevant HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make `z-index` work properly, you need to add positioning to the element. Don't ask why, I have no clue.

This should get you want you're looking for. Note that I added `position: relative;` to the top of both of them.

[Further reading](http://tjkdesign.com/articles/z-index/teach_yourself_how_elements_stack.asp)

```
.popup-title-side {
    position: relative;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Gamecube;
    font-size: 6px;
    color: #f00;
    line-height: 13px;
    cursor: default;
    z-index: 1001;
    background-color: #888;
}

.popup-body-side {
    position: relative;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Gamecube;
    font-size: 6px;
    line-height: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1000;
    /*min-height: 200px;*/
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: That's weird, but it works perfectly now

Comment: @user2856416 It's not weird, it's exactly how the W3C spec defines it :-)

Comment: but OP had position:relative before as well...

Comment: nvm he did not have it on the popup-title class

Comment: Yeah, never have understood it. One of the weird things of CSS. Regardsless of the spec. :) Nonetheless, if I've solved your problem, please consider clicking the checkmark underneath the arrows at the top of this post.

Comment: @Sai, yeah, missed that on the second one. I just scanned the first one and didn't see it, and that's the higher one.

Comment: @David sorry, I had to wait until my question hit 15 minutes to accept your post as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to add relative positioning. Add this to .popup-title-side

```
position: relative;
```

Answer (score 0):

Z-index doesn't work if there is no `position:relative, position:fixed or position:absolute` property set

Answer (score 0):

you should give .popup-title-side a `position:relative`, `position:absolute` or `position:fixed`